# How to print the pattern as follows in C?

Tags: c

```
#1234567
1#345678
23#56789
345#7890
4567#901
56789#12
678901#3
7890123#
```

Here is my code

```
int main() {
    int pattern;
    int rows, columns;

    printf("Enter the pattern: ");
    scanf("%d", & pattern);

    for (rows = 1; rows <= pattern; rows++) {
        for (columns = 1; columns <= pattern; columns++) {
            if (rows == columns)
                printf("#");
            else
                printf("%d", columns);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The next step is to look at the output from your program, and see where it differs from the expected output. Also, what was the input to the program?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to include the output you are getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start both inner and outer loop from *0 to pattern-1*. Print `(columns+rows)%10`. Your work will done. See the change in code bellow:

```
int main() {
    int pattern;
    int rows, columns;

    printf("Enter the pattern: ");
    scanf("%d", & pattern);

    for (rows = 0; rows < pattern; rows++) {
        for (columns = 0; columns < pattern; columns++) {
            if (rows == columns)
                printf("#");
            else
                printf("%d", (columns+rows)%10);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to not take an additional variable? Thanks.

Comment: Yes of course. It can be done by writing  (columns+rows)%10) instead of (columns+increment)%10). There are no need to add an additional variable. I edit my answer accordingly. See that, hope it will help you.